# Alternatives for For..in loop in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm getting an error with Delphi 7 on for in loop when compiling this code [Link](https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/getting-processor-info-using-object-pascal-delphi-fpc-and-the-tsmbios/)

```
procedure GetProcessorInfo;
Var
  SMBios             : TSMBios;
  LProcessorInfo     : TProcessorInformation;
  LSRAMTypes         : TCacheSRAMTypes;
begin
  SMBios:=TSMBios.Create;
  try
      WriteLn('Processor Information');
      if SMBios.HasProcessorInfo then
      for LProcessorInfo in SMBios.ProcessorInfo do // <-- Error here
      begin
        ...
      end;
  ...
end;
```

Error message:

> [Error] Project1.dpr(52): Operator not applicable to this operand type

Any alternative way ? or how can I fix it ?

Comment: `for .. in` is not supported by Delphi 7

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Delphi 7 does not support `for .. in`, so you have to iterate the `TSMBios.ProcessorInfo` array by yourself

```
procedure GetProcessorInfo;
Var
  SMBios             : TSMBios;
  LProcessorInfo     : TProcessorInformation;
  LSRAMTypes         : TCacheSRAMTypes;
  LIdx : Integer; // add this
begin
  SMBios:=TSMBios.Create;
  try
    WriteLn('Processor Information');
    if SMBios.HasProcessorInfo then
      // for LProcessorInfo in SMBios.ProcessorInfo do
      for LIdx := Low( SMBios.ProcessorInfo ) to High( SMBios.ProcessorInfo ) do
      begin
        LProcessorInfo := SMBios.ProcessorInfo[LIdx];
        ...
      end;
  ...
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The for in loop syntax was introduced in Delphi 2005. Delphi 7 does not support this syntax. You'll need to re-code the loop to use a traditional index based for loop.

```
for i := 0 to high( SMBios.ProcessorInfo ) do
begin
  LProcessorInfo := SMBios.ProcessorInfo[i];
  ....
end;
```